# Little trouble with fgets and error handling

Tags: c, fgets

i have recently started to learn C and have encountered a little problem with a code snipped.

I want want wo read a character string, 20 chars long, over the stdin, so I have chosen fgets.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
unsigned int length = 20;
char input_buffer[length];
fgets(input_buffer, length, stdin);
if(input_buffer == NULL)
    printf("Error, input too long");
else
    printf("%s", input_buffer);
return 0;
}
```

It compiles without any error, if I enter a sentence shorter than 20 characters, everything is fine. But when I try to test the error handling, it fails.

The output is:

```
peter@antartica ~/test % ./test    
Hello world, this is a very long test
Hello world, this i%
```

Am I doing anything wrong? I thought fgets returns a NULL pointer if it fails(which should be the case here)?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: If you are reading 20 characters form `stdin`, you likely are entering 20 + 1 `'\n'`, so code needs to store 21 `char`.  And strings need a `'\0'`, so now consider `unsigned int length = 20+1+1;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [fgets reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/):

> On success, the function returns str.
>
> If the end-of-file is
> encountered while attempting to read a character, the eof indicator is
> set (feof). If this happens before any characters could be read, the
> pointer returned is a null pointer (and the contents of str remain
> unchanged).
>
> If a read error occurs, the error indicator (ferror) is
> set and a null pointer is also returned (but the contents pointed by
> str may have changed).

So it may return `NULL` without generating an error in the event of reaching end-of-file. You may need to see `ferror` return value to be sure about it.

Please note `fgets()` will automatically append a null character (`\0`) to the end of the string, which may cause the string to be truncated, since you specify how many characters must be read. The call won't fail if a string with more than `length` characters is found.

Answer (score 3):

On error, `fgets()` *returns* `NULL`, but the contents of the buffer are indeterminate.

You are checking the buffer, not the return value.

Try:

```
if ( fgets(input_buffer, length, stdin) == NULL )
{
    printf("Error, input too long");
}
else
{
    printf("%s", input_buffer);
}
```

Good advice: *Always* use `{}`, even for one-line blocks. It really helps avoiding errors and makes code better readable.

**Edit:** +1 to Mauren: A too-long input line is actually not considered an error, but silently truncated, so your whole concept won't work as intended. If in doubt, always check the docs for the function you're using. Try `man fgets` -- on the command line in a Unix-ish environment, or if in a pinch, in a web search engine. ;)

Comment: This is actually the benefit of `fgets()`: you may iterate over a whole file reading small parts of it.

Comment: Thank you, well I didnt realize that, but it's only logical, I will take a look deeper in the commands.

Your sample code thought, also produces my error. I'll try playing with ferror(). Thanks

Comment: @Mauren: I would have remembered that if I had spent a couple more seconds thinking about it. I actually *implemented* `fgets()` in my own C library. ;-) Two nasty habits of mine: One, I answer SO questions while the compiler is running, i.e. always on the run. And two, once I find the first error, I usually consider the case closed, assuming there is only one error in there. ;-) You caught the second error, so credit where credit is due.